# Three.js: no luck updating cube textures on runtime with r59

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, mesh, texture-mapping

I created a cube using the canvas renderer with r59 of Three.js. The cube has different textures on different sides. This renders okay. I can also TWEEN this cube's position and rotation, so it's fine.

Here's what I want to do:
A) The cube has an image texture on it's front side.
B) I move this cube out of the camera's view.
C) I change the image texture on the cube.
D) I move the cube back to its original coordinates so it becomes visible again.

So far, steps A, B and D are working. But when I try to implement step C, it stops working.
Here are the relevant code parts...

```
<body>
    <script src="build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/tween.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var container;
        var camera, scene, renderer, group, particle;
        var cubeMesh;
        var MatCollection = [];
        var Materials = [];

        init();
        animate();

        function init() {
            container = document.createElement( 'div' );
            document.body.appendChild( container );
            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 3000 );
            camera.position.z = 1000;
            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            var cubeGeometry = new THREE.CubeGeometry(800, 600, 30, 8, 8, 8);
            cubeGeometry.dynamic = true;

            // creating three textures

            var neheTextureSMALL = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("test3.jpg");
            var neheTextureBIG1 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("break01.jpg");
            var neheTextureBIG2 = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("break02.jpg");


            // putting two different sets of Materials to a material collection array

            Materials = [
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureBIG1,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureSMALL,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureSMALL,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureSMALL,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureBIG1,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureBIG1,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                })
            ];

            MatCollection.push( Materials );

            Materials = [
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureBIG2,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureSMALL,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureSMALL,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureSMALL,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureBIG2,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
                    map:neheTextureBIG2,
                    side: THREE.DoubleSide
                })
            ];

            MatCollection.push( Materials );
            cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial( MatCollection[0] ));
            cubeMesh.dynamic = true;
            cubeMesh.position.set(0, 0, 500);

            // Applying the first set of materials on cubeMesh creation works good

            renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
            renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);
            renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
            container.appendChild( renderer.domElement );
        }
        function animate() {
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            render();
        }
        function render() {
            TWEEN.update();
            camera.lookAt( scene.position );

            // rotate the cube - dropped value manipulation

            cubeMesh.rotation.set(xRotation, yRotation, zRotation);

            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        }

        // this is NOT WORKING

        function changetexture() {
            currentMat++;
            if (currentMat >= MatCollection.length) {
                currentMat = 0;
            }
            cubeMesh.material = MatCollection[currentMat];
            cubeMesh.material.needsUpdate = true;

        }
    </script>
</body>
```

In my project, I am doing a lot more TWEENING (moving and rotating a lot of objects) and I am calling changetexture() from there...

When leaving out the line...

```
            cubeMesh.material = MatCollection[currentMat];
```

from that function, everything works fine. The cube moves out and comes back into view showing always the same texture.

What should I change?

Thank you in advance for sharing your expertise.

Oliver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done.

Instead of trying to preload the Material into an array of materials, I created an array of individual textures called MyTextures and applied a newly created material (using the textures from the MyTextures array) to each side of the cube mesh.

```
  ...
        var MyTextures = [];
  ... then, in the init() function:
            neheTextureSMALL = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture("test3.jpg");
            MyTextures.push( neheTextureSMALL );

            for (var myy = 0; myy<imgNameArray.length;myy++) {
                neheTexture = new THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture(imgNameArray[myy]);
                MyTextures.push( neheTexture );
            }

  ... then in the changetexture() function:

            cubeMesh.material.materials[0] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: MyTextures[currentMat+1], side: THREE.DoubleSide });
            cubeMesh.material.materials[1] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: MyTextures[0], side: THREE.DoubleSide });
            cubeMesh.material.materials[2] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: MyTextures[0], side: THREE.DoubleSide });
            cubeMesh.material.materials[3] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: MyTextures[0], side: THREE.DoubleSide });
            cubeMesh.material.materials[4] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: MyTextures[currentMat+1], side: THREE.DoubleSide });
            cubeMesh.material.materials[5] = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: MyTextures[currentMat+1], side: THREE.DoubleSide });
```

That works pretty well.
But it does not look good (the image seems to be split into many triangles which is another problem...). :-(